# how to print from android to receipt printer without any external SDK?

Tags: java, android, mobile, printing, android-print-framework

I am developing an application for Point of Sales. In that I want to take print from android mobile to any printer type(only receipt printer / kitchen printer) without using any SDK for particular printer.

Is this possible, or is it possible only by calling cloud Services?

Answer (score 0):

We print to thermal printers via bluetooth. We use the Star printer from Star Micronics. Our users print to these from their tablets when out in the field. It was a bit tricky getting them to work. You're a bit limited in what you can print from an Android device, and it took quite a bit of searching to find something that worked.